# Where should PowerShell function definitions be put in order to have it sourced automatically?

Tags: powershell

Given a simple PowerShell function:

```
function gpg {
    C:\Program files\GNU\GnuPG\gpgcmd.exe $args
}
```

Where should I put this function definition to make `gpg` available as a PowerShell command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it inside your [PowerShell Profile](https://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/)

The Profile always gets loaded when PowerShell starts, except when you call PowerShell with the `-NoProfile` Parameter, which is (at least in my network) rarely the case. So whenever PowerShell starts, you can use your functions right away.

If you want to create a PowerShell Profile for more than one computer, I'd use GPO to deploy the Profile from a source path to your destination computers.

Keep in mind that there are individual profiles for PowerShell and PowerShell_ISE

Answer (score 1):

As @SimonS mentioned one option is that you can put it in your profile.  And in your case of a simple function to help running a single command easier the profile probably is the right choice.  But I would like to mention another option.

If you are running a version of powershell greater then 3.0 on your systems then another choice is to put your function, or functions in a [Powershell module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878310.aspx).  Modules within your module path will be [automatically loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878284.aspx), and any exported functions will be available.  The module you create needs to be in the module path (`$env:psmodulePath`), a good location for system wide modules is `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

You really don't wan to put too much stuff into your profile.  First your profile is loaded when you start Powershell, and the more things you define there will have some impact on the speed Powershell loads.  Profiles are not automatically loaded when using PS remoting, but in modules that are in the path on the destination system are auto loaded.